# Permutations inside subsets of a list in python

Tags: python, permutation, combinatorics

I have a list and need to get all permutations. But I can do permutations only inside list subsets.

So for example I have list like this `[1,2,3,4]`

I split it into two subsets
`[1,2], [3,4]`

And I want to get an iterable which will give me

```
[1,2], [3,4]
[2,1], [3,4]
[1,2], [4,3]
[2,1], [4,3]
```

So it is equivalent to nested loops. But number of subsets can be different and I cant code it as loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
from itertools import permutations, product

x,y=[1,2],[3,4]

z=list(product(permutations(x), permutations(y)))
```

Outputs:

```py
[((1, 2), (3, 4)), ((1, 2), (4, 3)), ((2, 1), (3, 4)), ((2, 1), (4, 3))]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this

```
import itertools

subset= [1,2,3,4]
for sin itertools.combinations(subset, 2):
        print(s)
```